# Display Ok/Cancel alert for each iteration within server-side loop?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

Is it possible to display a popup for every iteration within a `for`, `foreach` or any other server-side loop in a webform?

Our gridview has 3 columns: `oldEmpId` and `newEmpId`, and a checkbox.And there's a button that updates all selected oldEmpIds with newEmpIds. But instead of doing it all in one shot, I would prefer some confirmation between each change.

For example, something like this:

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGridEmps.MasterTableView.Items)
{
    CheckBox ChkChange = item.FindControl("ChkChange") as CheckBox;
    if (ChkChange.Checked)
    {
        oldEmpId = item.GetDataKeyValue("oldEmpId").ToString();
        newEmpId = item.GetDataKeyValue("newEmpId").ToString();

        var msg = string.Format("Change from {0} to {1}?", oldEmpId, newEmpId);
        OkCancel_Popup(msg);

        if (OK)
            UpdateEmp(oldEmpId, newEmpId);
        else if (Cancel)
            //Do Nothing and go to following row
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to display a popup for each iteration? As a user, I would probably want to click a checkbox for rows in a grid rather than cycle through multiple dialog boxes.

Comment: What would be an available choice in a Desktop application cannot work in a web one: your code is running on the server, "creating" the HTML it will send to the browser in the response. your (multiple) questions to the user "are you sure" cannot happen within a loop running at server